# Showing default value after returning from each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do duplication checking on names while adding the records. Initially, I have assigned `value` to `false`. In case any mismatch, `value` is being changed to `true` inside the each loop and exit the loop. But outside the loop, `value` again shown as `false`.

```
function IsDuplicated(name) {
var value = false;    
masterTable = $('#example').DataTable();
var form_data = masterTable.rows().data();    
$.each(form_data, function (key, value) {
    alert(value.Name);
    if (name== value.Name) {            
        value = true;
        alert(value+ " 1")
        return false;
    }
});
alert(value+ " 2")
return value;
}
```

Can you help why it is changing to default value after returning from the each loop?

Comment: Inside your function you are changing the value of the argument `value` (in `function (key, value)`), not the global variable `value`. Change the name of one of them and the code should work...

Comment: `const IsDuplicated = name => [...$('#example').DataTable().rows().data()].some((key, value) => name == value.Name)`

Comment: Off Topic: you'll find it easier to debug if you use `console.log` instead of `alert`.

Answer (score 0):

It's cleaner if you do that using find instead

```
function IsDuplicated(name) {
   
   const masterTable = $('#example').DataTable();
   const data = masterTable.rows().data();    
   
   return !!data.find(d => d.Name == name)    
}
```